# Why do automotive airbag squib drivers support voltages up to 35 V?

Tags: power-supply

I have been looking at several airbag squib drivers lately and I found that most of the squib drivers on the market (such as MC33797 or L9659) have quite large firing voltage range, roughly from 7 to 35 V. I would guess that most of them are suited for 12 V cars so I am wondering why is there this tendency to support such high voltage? What am I missing here?

Comment: Most of that revolves around the squib itself.  They require a certain minimum voltage to guarantee that they fire/ignite.  One's I've dealt wirt in the past required much higher voltages, several hundred or thousands of volts to fire.

Comment: Automotive parts generally support high voltages in case of spikes on the main power bus - the "12V" is not at all clean.

Comment: Alternators are now controlled to put out up to 15.3V on some cars...

Answer (score 2):

The 12 V line in a car can briefly go up to **40 V** when the battery is removed **while the engine is running**.

You would not want the airbags to deploy when a mechanic disconnects the battery after forgetting to turn the engine off.

So most of the car electronics that are powered from 12 V have to be able to cope with 35 V or more, at least for a short time.

More detailed information in for example [this document from Texas Instruments](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tiduc41/tiduc41.pdf), page 5 shows some "nice" curves of supply pulses, the actual voltages are listed elsewhere in the document. Car manufacturers need the chips they use to support (survive without damage) this. If your chip doesn't (survive these pulses) then car manufacturers aren't going to buy your chip.

Comment: I think the main reason is due to flyback from solenoids. I worked for an aftermarket automotive company and it was possible to see voltage spikes as high as 50V on the 12V rail.

Answer (score 0):

I would also add that sometimes you'd like to make sure to be able to fire your squibs even if you lose you 12V supply (Which you might lose during the crash time frame). For that you would want to store energy which you can deploy in that scenario.

Now, the charge you need to deliver is linked to your storage caps $$I*\Delta t = C*Uc $$ So the higher the voltage, the smaller the caps you can use (Cheaper, smaller total footprint, etc)